# How can I prevent Safari (and other apps) from quitting?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, iterm, macos

Often times I will try to quit (for example) Slack, but accidentally quit Safari, and thus lose the arrangement of my millions  of Safari windows.  (This can happen if Safari is the top-most app, but without any visible windows.  If I don't look in the upper left-hand corner and actually read the app name, it may appear that Slack is selected because its window is visible on top.)

Since Apple only sees fit to restore windows to the proper desktop when you start up your Mac with windows being automatically opened, and otherwise opens them all in the same desktop (which is a horrible UX oversight!), I really really really want to avoid accidentally quitting Safari (or any other browser).  How can I easily prevent this from happening?

Manually customizing the keystrokes is a last resort, being kind of kludgey.

Comment: Just to clarify (and not being flippant) you want to quit an app, but prevent other apps from quitting because you inadvertently told the wrong app to quit.  How do you see this working, exactly?  How is an app going to interpret whether or not the “quit” signal was for it or not?

Comment: Google Chrome has a preference whereby you need to hold down Command-Q for longer than usual for it to quit. I use Chrome almost exclusively because of this feature. That and needing to use it for GApps for work, as there is better integration.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to Change Safari's (or other applications') keyboard shortcut for quitting, as suggested here:

[Warn before quitting in Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151264/warn-before-quitting-in-safari)